# OpportunityContactRole security

Tags: opportunity, security, contact, opportunitycontactrole

In a nutshell, **how from the REST API (outside the Apex wall here), can I tell I can create/edit/remove an OpportunityContactRole from scratch.**

**Part I of the answer** is I believe the OpportunityContactRole exists in the Sobject Global and is createable.

**Part II of the answer** for an existing item is to query the UserRecordAccess of the specific record.

It's the specific scenario of CREATING a new one that is sometimes failing for me.

> This is not sufficient however. In testing, we've found adding a
>   ContactRole to an Opportunity (that the user doesn't own) can fail
>   with an INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY.

I believe that the **answer to this is to query the UserRecordAccess of the referenced Opportunity and Contacts and make sure you have Edit access to both of them** (I assume Delete and Transfer are not needed for just creating, and I definitely had Read access).

In short I am saying

> You can create an OCR as long as the metadata exists, returns
>   isCreateable, AND the referenced Contact and Opportunity you have EDIT
>   acccess to

Is this correct?

Comment: FYI - that's the logic I went with and so far seems to work. Will update if more info arises.